# How can I prove Chebyshev's sum inequality with probabilistic methods?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities

I would like to prove Chebyshev's sum inequality, which states that:

If $a_1\geq a_2\geq \cdots \geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq \cdots \geq b_n$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k\geq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right)
$$
I am familiar with the non-probabilistic proof, but I need a probabilistic one.

Comment: for a _physics_ proof (relying on the mechanics of the center of mass), see [Picard’s Weighty Proof of Chebyshev’s Sum Inequality](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0025570X.2018.1512814?scroll=top&needAccess=true)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A$ be the random variable attaining the values $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ with equal probabilities, and define $B$ similarly, subject to $\mathbb P(B=b_i|A=a_i)=1$. Then $\mathbb E(A)=\frac1n\,\sum_{1\le i\le n} a_i$, $\mathbb E(B)=\frac1n\,\sum_{1\le i\le n} b_i$, and $\mathbb E(AB)=\frac1n\,\sum_{1\le i\le n} a_ib_i$. Since $a_i$ and $b_i$ are similarly ordered, we have $\mathrm{Cov}(A,B)>0$ whence $\mathbb E(AB)\ge\mathbb E(A)\mathbb E(B)$.

Comment: "Since $a_i$ and $b_i$ are similarly ordered, we have ${\rm Cov}(A,B)>0$" - is this somehow obvious? Looks like essentially the same statement which should be proved.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Well taken. Seems you are right when it comes to a formal proof, and yet on the intuitive level, this is considered the most standard property of covariance. So maybe what I have written is more of an informal, but convincing explanation, than a rigorous proof.

Comment: I like the following informal explanation of Chebyshev/rearrangement inequality: if you buy 17 sportcars, 10 smartphones and 3 apple pies you clearly pay more than when you buy 17 smartphones, 10 pies and 3 sportcars, or any other permutation, or if you buy 17+10+3 items for an average price. This is pretty intuitive, what is here to prove at all?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You are right, as always. I'd better refrain from writing anything else today.

Comment: Ah, this may be fixed: after we made $\mathbb{E} A=0$, there exists $c$ such that $A(B-c)\geqslant 0$.

Comment: "Since $a_i$ and $b_i$ are similarly ordered, we have $\mathrm{Cov}(A,B)>0$" is obvious for $n=2$ with no equalities.  So you can increase $\sum a_ib_i$ by pairwise rearrangements until the two sequences have similar orderings overall

Comment: @Henry how does this argument prove that the covariance is positive? they are already ordered similarly.

Comment: @FedorPetrov If the orderings were random, the expected covariance would be zero.  But (using the pairwise rearrangement argument) the similarly ordered sequences give the maximum covariance, this must be positive

Comment: @Henry well, I see. For me, that's essentially the standard proof rephrased in probabilistic terms.

Answer (score 12):

A more general inequality is
$$Ef(X)g(X)\ge Ef(X)\,Eg(X),\tag{1}$$
where $f$ and $g$ are nondecreasing (say bounded) functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and $X$ is any real-valued random variable. (In your case, $X$ is uniformly distributed on the set $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, whereas $f$ and $g$ are any nondecreasing bounded functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(j)=a_j$ and $g(j)=b_j$ for all $j\in[n]$.)

To prove (1), note that $(f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y))\ge0$ for all real $x$ and $y$, since $f$ and $g$ are nondecreasing. Therefore, letting $Y$ denote an independent copy of $X$, we have
$$0\le E(f(X)-f(Y))(g(X)-g(Y)) \\ 
=Ef(X)g(X)+Ef(Y)g(Y)-Ef(X)g(Y)-Ef(Y)g(X) \\
=Ef(X)g(X)+Ef(Y)g(Y)-Ef(X)\,Eg(Y)-Ef(Y)\,Eg(X) \\
=Ef(X)g(X)+Ef(X)g(X)-Ef(X)\,Eg(X)-Ef(X)\,Eg(X) \\
=2[Ef(X)g(X)-Ef(X)\,Eg(X)],$$
whence (1) follows.

Comment: The first inequality ("0 <= ...") is not trivial, and does not follow immediately from the "note that".

Comment: @einpoklum : This inequality is a particular case of the following: If a random variable $Z$ is nonnegative, then $EZ\ge0$. Does this look nontrivial for you?

Comment: But you didn't apply the expectation to a variable. You applied it to one multiplicand out of two, which you have not established is nonnegative. ... or - maybe you've just gotten the parentheses wrong? I think that might be it.

Comment: @einpoklum : Of course, the expectation is of the product, not of the first factor. It is a standard and convenient convention to write $EX$ and $EXYZ$  for $E[X]$ and $E[XYZ]$; see e.g. the two-line display near the middle of page 1685 in the paper at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176988477 . Otherwise, the multiline display in my answer here would have to contain a huge number of brackets and look terrible, I think. (It helps to remember that $E$ is a linear operator, and no brackets or parentheses are needed to express the action of such an operator.)

Comment: The application of the E to the entire produced is non-standard enough for me, with a Ph.D. in theoretical Comp Sci, not to realize that's what you were doing. So, changed it.

Comment: @einpoklum : It may also help to remember that the expectation is, not just a linear operator, but also an integral one. So, to me $E[XY]$ looks a bit like $\int[fg]$ or, the horror! :-), like maybe $\int[f(x)g(x)dx]$.

Comment: @einpoklum : BTW, the expectation of the first factor in that product is $0$, so that the inequality in question, even as you first understood it, is obviously true. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this counts, but you may do the following.

At first, you may suppose that $a_n>0$ (otherwise replace all $a_i$ to $a_i-a_n+1$). Consider the probabilistic distribution $\mu$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $p_i={\rm prob} (X=i)=a_i/(a_1+\ldots+a_n)$. Then $p_1+\ldots+p_n=1$, $p_1\geqslant \ldots \geqslant p_n$, and we want to prove that $\mathbb{E}_{\mu} b\geqslant \mathbb{E}_{\lambda} b\,\, (*),$ where $\lambda$ is a uniform distribution, and $b:i\to b_i$ is a decreasing function. For doing this we construct a coupling, that is, a joint distribution $\nu$ of $(X,Y)\in\{1,\ldots,n\}^2$ such that $X$ is distributed as $\mu$, $Y$ as $\lambda$ and $Y\geqslant X$. This gives $(*)$ since $$\mathbb{E}_{\mu} b=\mathbb{E}_\nu b(X)\geqslant \mathbb{E}_\nu b(Y)=\mathbb{E}_\lambda b.$$
For constructing $\nu$, partition the semiinterval $[0,1)$ onto $n$ semiintervals $\Delta_1,\ldots,\Delta_n$ (from left to right) of lengths $1/n$ and semiintervals $\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n$ of lengths $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. Choose a random point $x\in [0,1]$ at uniform and denote $(X,Y)=(k,i)$ if $x\in \Delta_i\cap \delta_k$.

It remains to prove that $i\geqslant k$. Assume the contrary: $k>i$. Then $x\geqslant p_1+\ldots+p_i\geqslant ip_i$; $1-x\leqslant p_{i+1}+\ldots+p_n\leqslant (n-i)p_i$; $x/i\geqslant p_i\geqslant (1-x)/(n-i)$; $x\geqslant i/n$; $x\notin \Delta_i$. A contradiction.